# How do you hide a specific column in a table on SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on setting up security permissions on a specific database on SQL Server Management Studio. One specific request is we need to hide a specific data column from being seen to the specific user role.

We want the table to be viewable by the user role, but we don't want a specific data column to be able to be viewed by that user role.

How do I go about hiding that column to that specific user role?

Is it through a query or is it within the permissions for that specific table?

Comment: what version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Create a view that excludes that column.

Comment: @trailmax It's SQL Server 2012

Comment: @jarlh Could you elaborate a bit more, like do I create the view within a query command?

Answer (score 5):

- [Create a view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) on the table that doesn't select the column you wish to hide, use the `CREATE VIEW` statement.

  > Creates a virtual table whose contents (columns and rows) are defined by a query. Use this statement to create a view of the data in one or more tables in the database.
- [Grant permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) on that view for the role, using the `GRANT` command.

  > Grants permissions on a securable to a principal.
- [Deny permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx) on the table for the role, using the `DENY` command.

  > Denies a permission to a principal. Prevents that principal from inheriting the permission through its group or role memberships.

Comment: So I went to the database folder, then right clicked on views and clicked create a new view. So I highlighted all the columns I want to keep and left the column I don't want to be viewed unticked, where do I go from here in terms of granting the permissions and then deny permissions as I'm a bit confused.